# Why does returning a malloc'd pointer here result in "HEAP CORRUPTION" on free?

Tags: c++, c, string, memory-management

**note: please suppress comments about "C++?  Use std::string!"**.  This question is using C strings but is more about memory management than strings in general.

I have this function

```
char* strclone( char* src )
{
    char* dst = (char*)malloc(strlen(src+1));
    strcpy(dst,src);
    return dst;
}
```

The function should work to allocate a new pointer (in `strclone`), write the string in src to it, and return the address of the new string.

However, when the string is `free`d, some time later in the program:

```
str = strclone( some_str_variable );    
// ..code..
free( str ) ; //! ERROR!
```

The error reads:

> Debug Error!
>
> Program: C:\...
>
> HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#39713) at 0x090CC448.
> CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.

The error occurs at the line where I call `free( str )` in the program.  If I change the assignment of str to this:

```
str = (char*)malloc( strlen( some_string_variable ) +1);
strcpy( str, some_string_variable ) ;
//...
free( str ) ; //fine now
```

Then there is no bug, the program functions perfectly.

Why does the `strclone` function not work as expected?

Comment: Can you post a **complete** example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @Oli: one line is enough, don't bother!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe that the problem is that you've written

```
(char*)malloc(strlen(src+1));
```

Notice that in the call to `strlen`, you have written

```
strlen(src + 1)
```

instead of

```
strlen(src) + 1
```

This first line says "the length of the string starting one character past `src`," which is the length of the string minus one (or total garbage if the string is empty).  The second one is the one you want - the length of the string plus one for the null terminator.  If you use the first version, then in the line

```
strcpy(dst,src);
```

You will end up writing past the end of the buffer, leading to the dreaded Undefined Behavior.  In your case, this was manifesting itself with a heap corruption error when you try to free the block, which makes sense because you have indeed corrupted the heap!

Try moving the +1 out of the parentheses and see if it fixes things.

Alternatively, most compilers ship with a nonstandard function called `strdup` that does exactly what your above function attempts to do.  You might want to consider just using that instead.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Note that despite the assertion that it's "more about memory management than strings in general", this really turns out to be a C string (`strlen`) problem. That's why C strings are so dangerous; it is too easy to convince yourself that you're doing it right even when all the facts point the other way.

Answer (score 4):

`strlen(src+1)` is not the same as `strlen(src)+1`.  So you are overwriting the bounds of your array by two elements when you do to the `strcpy`.

So I think the following is justified: **C++? Use `std::string`!**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`malloc(strlen(src)+1);`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should have typed

```
char* dst = (char*)malloc(strlen(src) + 1);
```

instead of

```
char* dst = (char*)malloc(strlen(src+1));
```

Answer (score 0):

The error happens because you are actually writing past the allocated memory.
change your malloc line to this:

```
char* dst = (char*)malloc(strlen(src)+1);
```

Because in your original implementation, you're advancing the pointer by 1, and then you pass that to strlen(), which will give you the lenght of the string-1. Since you also need the NULL at the end, you're actually off-by-2.